# blank space issue with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to disable some specific inputs like this with jquery :

```
$("input[value=" + resultId[i].name + "]" ).prop('disabled', true);
$("input[value=" + resultId[i].name + "]" ).css({ 'background-color: ', #D4D0C8' });
```

My problem is when `resultId[i].name` contains spaces like `tour eiffel` it doesn't work. I get an error:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: input[value=tour eiffel] ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the value in **single quotes** `'`:

```
$("input[value='" + resultId[i].name + "']").prop('disabled', true);
//             ^                        ^
$("input[value='" + resultId[i].name + "']").css({
    //         ^                        ^
    'background-color': '#D4D0C8'
    //               ^
});
```

Also, you missed the quote of `background-color`.

Answer (score 3):

When the value contains a space you *have* to wrap it in quotes:

```
$('input[value="' + resultId[i].name + '"]').prop('disabled', true);
$('input[value="' + resultId[i].name + '"]').css({ 'background-color': '#D4D0C8' });
```

Also note you were missing a quote in your `css()` object.